# Android Fragments - dealing with the backbutton

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am launching some fragments from my options menu, for example a preference fragment and a dialog fragment.

When I open the preferences fragment and hit the back button the entire activity closes.  This is not the case for the dialog fragment that works as I'd expect.

Could someone explain why this is happening and what is the accepted way of handling please? :)

To launch preference fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .addToBackStack("settings")
                .commit();
```

Comment: One could also use PreferenceActivity as the main Settings.

Answer (score 8):

Related to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665326/23947).

I had the exact same problem with the preferences fragment. It seems most people must give up and use a Preference Activity instead.

Your first problem that you are going to encounter is that you need to use **replace** instead of **add** when launching the fragment. That code should change to look like so:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .addToBackStack("settings")
                .commit();
```

As for handling the back button, it appears that the "back stack" is something that is not automatically triggered with the ***system*** back button. My solution was to manually pop the back stack from the ***onBackPressed*** override:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (inSettings)
    {
        backFromSettingsFragment();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Whenever I navigate to my preferences fragment, I set the *inSettings* boolean to true in the activity to retain that state. Here is what my *backFromSettingsFragment* method looks like:

```
private void backFromSettingsFragment()
{
    inSettings = false;
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could further explain the statement "..it appears that the "back stack" is something that is not automatically triggered with the system back button."

Comment: Sure. I was originally working under the assumption that popping a fragment manager's back stack would be something that was simply "built in" and handled within the Android SDK itself, if you were using a FragmentActivity. Thus working under this assumption, popping the back stack would automatically be handled for the developer whenever the back button is pressed and a back stack exists. I was trying to point out that this is NOT, indeed, the case and the developer has to handle the back button press manually. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If there is not any clear reason you named your back stack state, use `null` as argument:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```