# addToBackStack doesn't work, closes the activity instead of popping back fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack

I have a probleam and I can't find a solution anywhere.

My app doesn't return to previous fragment when I press the back button, instead closes the activity.

I have an activity that displays 4 fragment: [1],[2],[3],[4]. I can switch between the first 3 fragments with the action bar, I don't want to add them to the back stack.

Fragment [4] is a detailed view of an item selected in fragment [3]. When I press back in [4] I want to return to fragment [3], not closing the app.

The transitions are done in this way BY THE ACTIVITY in which fragments are placed:

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean toBackStack){

    if(fragment != null){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

        if(toBackStack)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

where toBackStack is always false except when the transition is from [3] to [4].

If I pass toBackStack true in every transition, the activity closes anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem. Specifically, I am implementing a PreferenceFragment and I want the back button to return me to whatever the previously loaded fragment was.

It appears that the "back stack" is something that is not automatically triggered with the ***system*** back button. My solution was to manually pop the back stack from the ***onBackPressed*** override:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (inSettings)
    {
        backFromSettingsFragment();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Whenever I navigate to my preferences fragment, I set the *inSettings* boolean to true in the activity to retain that state. Here is what my *backFromSettingsFragment* method looks like:

```
private void backFromSettingsFragment()
{
    inSettings = false;
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

So, if you are able to track the state of when you are in Fragment [4] and intercept the back button, you should be able to manually call

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

to go back to Fragment [3].

Note: remember that you need to add Fragment [3] to the back stack, ***not*** Fragment[4]. (Unless [4] goes to [5] and you need to back to [4] as well.)

Comment: So rather than holding state in the Activity it might be better to do this in onBackPressed()

if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();